# How can I say "$T \to \infty$ implies ..."?

Tags: limits, terminology, article-writing

I would like to know a better way to say "$T \rightarrow \infty$ implies ..." when writing / speaking.

I tend to write this as "Limiting $T$ to $\infty$ implies ...",
but others have told me that this particular phrasing sounds awkward.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: "As $T$ goes to infinity, one have..." ?

Comment: @FlorianIngels Ah, there is a simple and clear solution :) Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to phrase it. Some examples include:

- As T tends to infinity, it follows that . . .
- Taking the limit as T approaches infinity, gives the result . . .
- . . .  when we take the limit as T approaches infinity
- If we limit to T to infinity, this tells us that . . .

If you are writing this mathematically rather than speaking it aloud, there are some more concise ways of putting this depending on the context. For example:

- $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ [result] = [outcome]
- As we let T $\rightarrow\infty$, [result] $\implies$ [outcome] is true
- [expression] $\rightarrow$ [value]

However, these don’t mean the same thing and so it’s important that you don’t use them interchangeably, as they are all appropriate in different contexts.

**Edit:** Thanks to Snaw for the suggesting the third example in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. I’ve added some examples of mathematical ways to phrase this as well @JinraeKim

Comment: Should it really be "[result] $\implies$ [outcome]"? I think I've always seen this written as"[result] $\to$ [outcome]".

Comment: I made [result] and [outcome] a bit ambiguous, so  I’ve modified my answer to make it a bit clearer @Snaw

Comment: I meant the usage of $\implies$. I don't think I've seen it used for a limiting process. I believe the standard notation for that is $\to$.

Comment: I think there may be a bit of confusion. I am also taking it to mean implies. This should read as “taking the limit as T approaches infinity for [result] implies that [outcome] is true”. Note: [outcome] is a direct corollary of [result] which we have derived by taking limits @Snaw

Comment: If "→∞ implies [result/outcome]”, then for the latter part of the last three bullets, perhaps something like “[expression] $\to$ [value] “ instead.